# I am trying to figure out how to embed links or hyperlink elements inside of a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, hyperlink

I am trying to figure out how to embed the links from mlb.com for each player to the player inside of a list. So, when I click on the player's name then I will get directed to the mlb.com page for that player. For example, if I click on [Yordan Alvarez](https://www.mlb.com/player/yordan-alvarez-670541) it would take me to his stats since it would be embedded into Yordan Alvarez.

This is what I have tried so far, but I am currently stuck. How would I be able to embed the links inside of the players so that it works like this [Yordan Alvarez](https://www.mlb.com/player/yordan-alvarez-670541)?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import re 

# Request URL 

url_1 = 'https://www.mlb.com/stats/'
req = requests.get(url_1).text
document = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')

# Body 

tbody = document.tbody

# Headers

thead = document.thead 

# Player Names 

full_name = tbody.find_all('a') 

# List of Players 

players_list = []

for name in full_name: 
    if name.get('aria-label'):
        names = name.get('aria-label')
        players_list.append(names)

# List of Links

hrefs_list = []

hrefs = tbody.find_all('a',href = True) 

# Players & Their Links 

for link,player in zip(hrefs, players_list):
    href_link = link['href']
    if re.search('^/player', href_link):
        stats_link = f'https://www.mlb.com{href_link}'
        hrefs_list.append(stats_link)
        hyperlink_format = f'<a href= {stats_link}>{player}</a>'
print(dict(zip(players_list, hrefs_list)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the fact that `find_all` can use regexp on attributes.
Combining this with a dict comprehension would simplify this to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import re 

base_url = 'https://www.mlb.com'
stats_url = f'{base_url}/stats/'
req = requests.get(stats_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')

pattern = re.compile(r"/player/\d+")
links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': pattern})

{a.text: f"{base_url}/{a.attrs.get('href')}" for a in links}
```

Comment: @UBIYTSV So can you accept one of the awnsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid multiple lists that should be zipped, cause they should have the same length, instead try to collect your data in one go.

You could use `css selectors` to select the links / player names and depending on the expected result you could create a `dict`:

```
{a.get('aria-label'): f"{base_url}{a.attrs.get('href')}" for a in soup.select('a[href^="/player/"]')}
```

or a list of dicts:

```
data = []

for a in soup.select('a[href^="/player/"]'):
    data.append({
        'name':a.get('aria-label'),
        'url':f"{base_url}{a.attrs.get('href')}"
    })
data
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

base_url = 'https://www.mlb.com'
req = requests.get(f'{base_url}/stats/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req)

data = []

for a in soup.select('a[href^="/player/"]'):
    data.append({
        'name':a.get('aria-label'),
        'url':f"{base_url}{a.attrs.get('href')}"
    })
data
```

###### Output

```
[{'name': 'Yordan Alvarez', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/670541'},
 {'name': 'Paul Goldschmidt', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/502671'},
 {'name': 'Mike Trout', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/545361'},
 {'name': 'Aaron Judge', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/592450'},
 {'name': 'Bryce Harper', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/547180'},
 {'name': 'Rafael Devers', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/646240'},
 {'name': 'Jose Ramirez', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/608070'},
 {'name': 'Manny Machado', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/592518'},
 {'name': 'Pete Alonso', 'url': 'https://www.mlb.com/player/624413'},...]
```

Comment: @UBIYTSV So can you accept one of the awnsers?